# Google spreadsheet API: Create spreadsheet from templatewith drive.file scope

Tags: python, api, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm working on a python script, that creates a spreadsheet with the Google Spreadsheet API and then reads values from that.
My problem is, that for creating the spreadsheet, I want to use a template or copy an existing spreadsheet. Because I don't want to use the spreadsheet.read but only the drive.file scope, I cannot read from the public template sheet. Is there any way to work around this, and still use that specific sheet as a template, without having the larger scope?

The code I'm trying to access with is following:

```py
    dest_body = {
        'destination_spreadsheet_id': new_spreadsheet_id,
    }
    jobs_sheet = service.spreadsheets().sheets().copyTo(
        spreadsheetId=template_id, sheetId=SHEETID, body=dest_body).execute()
```

When accessing my template sheet (which is shared publicly), I get this error:

```
<HttpError 404 when requesting ... returned "Requested entity was not found.">
```

The service is created with this function, which can be also found here https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python:

```
def get_authenticated_service_sheets():
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'])

    if os.path.exists('src/util/token.pickle'):
        with open('src/util/token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        creds = flow.run_local_server()
        with open('src/util/token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    return build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
```

Comment: Please add your code, and evtl. the error log. This helps others to reproduce your issue. Please also check [example]

Comment: I tried to keep it as minimal as possible. I hope it's clearer now, what the issue is.

Comment: You could access the public spreadsheet with an API key. Since `copyTo` requires OAuth, though, this wouldn't be so direct. You could use the content retrieved by the previous call with the API key to create a new spreadsheet, and use this new spreadsheet to copy your desired sheet. What do you think of this?

Comment: In that case, I would only get the values of the sheet, but no formatting. Is that correct?

Comment: You could also retrieve the formatting, which is a property of [Cell](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#CellFormat). And you could set it in the copied sheet (see [this](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/formatting)). Are there other properties you'd need to keep? Do you think this would be appropriate for your situation? If that's the case, I'd consider posting this as an answer.